# Java adding to table data issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, frame

Can someone tell me, where is my mistake? 
I'm trying to fill up table with data but I can't, always get empty table.
Here is my code with frame:

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class Rinktis extends JFrame {
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private JTable table;

        public Rinktis() 
        {

        super();
        setBounds(100, 100, 861, 375);      
        try {
            jbInit();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    Vector<Vector<String>> data1 =new Vector<Vector<String>>(); 
Vector<String> heading1 = new Vector<String>();
    public void tab(Vector heading, Vector data)
    {   System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(heading);    
        data1=data;
        heading1=heading;
        System.out.println(data1);
        System.out.println(heading1);
    }   
    private void jbInit() throws Exception {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 10, 825, 176);     

        table = new JTable(data1,heading1);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }

}
```

Here's how I call it from another frame:

```
    protected void rinktisButton_1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{       Rinktis frame = new Rinktis();
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    try {
        db.getClients();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and from `db.getClients();` I call `rinktis.tab(columnHeads,v);`
`System.out.println` gives me all data correctly, but table is empty.

Comment: no data added from `db.getClients();` to the JTable, nothing else I assumed three states 1) you are really forget for that 2) very bad day for you is today because nobody going to make your job for you 3) you have to split your question to 3-4 separeted thread a) about JDBC, b) how to pass ResultSet to the TableModel, c) how to LayoutManagers works d) how to JTable works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your tab function to be like this:

```
public void tab(Vector heading, Vector data)
    {       
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data,heading) );
    }
```

Comment: @camickr still I think your answer is better as it has extra info about the problem so i will upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

For a serius answer you need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Anyway it seems that you are passing a wrong type to JTable [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

You need to pass a 2d array of object (`Object [][]`) or `Vector<Vector<Object>>` not plain 1D Vector, same as for TableHeader

I think here's the problem :

```
table = new JTable(data1, heading1); 
      //data1 need to of type Object[][] or Vector<Vector<Object>>
      //heading1 need to of type String[] or Vector<String>
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: no your wrong, i is possible to pass vector instead of 2d array

Comment: There is one `JTable` constructor that does accept two `Vector` arguments.

Comment: mmm.you are right. but remember that data1 Vector should be a Vector containing Vector. Is that the case? Anyway without an SSCCE or the complete code is difficult to tell what's happening.

Comment: i made some changes, but the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the table does not know that you changed the data. You can either load your data on creation of the table. Then it should show up just fine (maybe try this out first). Then in a second step you should work directly with the tablemodel and change data there. Whenever you do so call the you can notify the table to update.

Alternatively, if you already know your header, you can set it and only add the data later. This also should work. However I do not recommend this.